# Decorator addEventListener binding not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

I am trying to create a decorator that will take a method in a class and add it to an event listener on the window. However, when I do so it isn't binding to the class, and I am not sure why...

```js
export function Listener(listenerLocation: string) {
  return (target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const [nodeOrEvent, event] = listenerLocation.split(':')
    console.log(target)

    if (nodeOrEvent === 'window' && event.length > 0) {
      window.addEventListener(event, target[key].bind(target.constructor))
    }
  }
}
```

The log in the decorator prints the following:

[image: Resize decorator output]

```js
export class Canvas {
  constructor(
    public readonly width: number,
    public readonly height: number,
    public readonly canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | string
  ) {
    console.log(this.width)
    // Set width/height on canvas
  }

  @Listener('window:resize')
  windowResize() {
    console.log('w', this.width)
  }
}
```

When the class loads, the `console.log` in the constructor outputs the correct size of `-1` (tells the class to resize the canvas to max width), but then when I resize the window, the listener runs, but `this.width` is `undefined`.

### Edit

I have made some changes to the decorator, I am not sure if it is binding or not, but the output is still `undefined`.

```js
export function Listener(listenerLocation: string) {
  return (target: any, key: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const [nodeOrEvent, event] = listenerLocation.split(':')

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      configurable: true,
      get() {
        console.log('here', this)
        const bound = descriptor.value.bind(this)
        Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
          value: bound,
          configurable: true,
          writable: true
        })
        return bound
      }
    })

    if (nodeOrEvent === 'window' && event.length > 0) {
      window.addEventListener(event, target[key])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably need to bind windowResize to this in constructor.

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy I found a way to bind to `this`, however it still isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

As the windowResize method Decorator is getting called before creating instance, the width is not getting binded to the windowResize function.
As we have to bind only after creating instance, we can think of adding a class Decorater and extend construction functionality.
https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-chihiro-mungp?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:0-627

```js
import {
  Component
} from "@angular/core";
type Consturctor = {
  new(...args: any[]): any
};

function ResizeListener < T extends Consturctor > (BaseClass: T) {
  return class extends BaseClass {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.windowResize.bind(this));
    }
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
@ResizeListener
export class AppComponent {
  title = "CodeSandbox";
  constructor() {
    console.log("w", "IN parent");
  }
  windowResize() {
    console.log("w", this.title);
  }
}
```